# Google Forms Apps Script List onChange

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, onchange, google-forms

Is it possible in Apps Script of a Google Form to listen for a selection on a list `option`?

I assume no as I can't find any information on this.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093012/how-do-i-detect-when-i-view-an-email-in-gmail-with-google-apps-script-script/41093711#41093711

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible.  You would need to design a form in HTML, and use Apps Script HTML Service as a Stand Alone App.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GoToPage option of a Multiple Choice question, to send the user to a different set of options, but you have no control over what is happening to the form via script until after the data is submitted.