# How do I detect when I view an email in gmail with google-apps-script script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to trigger a script every time I view an email in gmail. Does anyone know if there a trigger for detecting this which i can bind to?

I'm open to doing this with any platform, not just google-apps-script.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible with the external API, but you might want to look at the documentation to set up a "watch" and a push notification.  [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) and [Link to Watch](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch)

Comment: @SandyGood: Great idea!

Answer (score 3):

## Short answer

At this time Google Apps Script doesn't have a triggers for Gmail events.

## Explanation

On Google Apps Script there are three kinds of scripts, bounded, stand-alone and web apps, and two kinds of triggers, simple and installable

Scripts only could be bounded to documents, forms and spreadsheets.

The available simple triggers are:

- onOpen(e)<sup>1,2,3</sup>
- onEdit(e)<sup>2</sup>
- onInstall(e)<sup>4</sup>
- doGet(e)<sup>5</sup>
- doPost(e)<sup>5</sup>

The available installable triggers are:

- Time-driven triggers
- Google Apps triggers

  - on open<sup>1,2,3</sup>
  - on edit<sup>2</sup>
  - on change<sup>2</sup>
  - on submit form<sup>2,3</sup>

### Triggers by app

The triggers works on the following "environments":

1. Google Documents editor
2. Google Sheets editor
3. Google Forms editor
4. Add-ons
5. Web Apps

Note: There are no simple nor installable that works on the Google Forms Viewer (response submission).

## References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events