# Gmail Add-on trigger criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

Can someone accurately describe the trigger criteria for Gmail Add-on scripts? Apparently, the trigger is not invoked each time the user navigates between Gmail conversations.

The only documentation I can find is https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/building#note1, which states

> the only contextual trigger type available is unconditional, which triggers for all emails regardless of content.

I interpreted this to mean that the trigger is invoked every time the user navigates to a different gmail conversation, however, that is not the case:

The first time I navigate to a some Gmail conversation, the add-on trigger fires. And when I navigate to another conversation using the the “Newer” or “Older” angle-bracket button, the trigger is again invoked for the new conversation. But when I navigate **back** to the first page using an angle bracket button, the add-on trigger does **not** fire. (Easy enough to show this by displaying a timestamp when each UI card is created.) There seems to be some kind of internal caching going on — is there any way to disable this, or otherwise run my add-on script *each time* the user navigates between Gmail conversations?

Comment: No response, as expected. Typical of Google to direct support questions to Stack Overflow, and then ignore them. Disappointing, but not surprising. We are on our own...

Comment: Consider filing a bug report on the Gmail Add-on Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:325133

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use ActionResponseBuilder.setStateChanged(), to clear the cache

link: https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/interactions

Comment: I have not verified that this works, but it sure seems like the way to go. I switched to [inboxsdk](https://www.inboxsdk.com/) over a year and a half ago.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Google Apps Script doesn't have triggers for Gmail events so the trigger will not invoke every time, the user navigates to a different Gmail conversation. Whenever a new message open it will invoke trigger, contextual trigger. You can also tryout **time-driven trigger** which invokes after each time interval. To use time-driven trigger open your project on https://script.google.com/. In Apps Script Editor, navigate to **Edit -> All your triggers**. If there is no trigger then setUp one and Save. See this example [Create Time-driven trigger in Gmail-add on](https://goolgedev.blogspot.com/2018/05/create-time-driven-trigger-in-gmail-add.html)

Refer this link for more information [How do I detect when I view an email in gmail with google-apps-script script? I think this might be helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093012/how-do-i-detect-when-i-view-an-email-in-gmail-with-google-apps-script-script?rq=1)

Comment: It seems that time-driven triggers are not available in Gmail addons: https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/restrictions Do you confirm @JaiPrak?

Comment: Google Apps Script has no simple or installable triggers but it has time-driven triggers. How to use them, I am updating my answer.

Comment: Are you speaking about Google apps script in general or Gmail add-ons ?  The latter seems to have no time driven : https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/restrictions

Comment: Gmail add ons require a manifest to enable other users to use it, in the manifest I don't think it's possible to put a time driven trigger.

Comment: Yes, you can. No need to put the time-driven trigger in the manifest and I haven't seen any example to setup time-driven trigger in manifest except contextual triggers. Once just try to create simple time-trigger in your project and in trigger method just put this there 
`function myTrigger(){
  Logger.log('Some message');
}` Set trigger time for every minute. Each minute you will see the logger message with respective time of the trigger call.

Comment: Can you add an answer with code example @JaiPrak showing how to create such a time driven trigger in a Gmail add on ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For example please go this link https://goolgedev.blogspot.com/2018/05/create-time-driven-trigger-in-gmail-add.html

Comment: The trigger is getting disabled, if we install it in the way suggested in the blog post.