# How to prevent Gmail Add-on (gadget) from caching?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am debugging a Google Apps Script and the UI on the right side of the page (Gmail addons).

However, each time I load an add-on then reloading the same Gmail message will not regenerate that add-on for 10+ minutes.

How can I disable this cache to make debugging easier?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50511085/gmail-add-ons-ontriggerfunction-only-ran-once-per-email-even-if-opening-the-emai

Comment: Thank you, yes. this is a duplicate of that question.