# Make http request on gmail addon when card is opened

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I'm writing a gmail addon with appscript and I want it to perform an http request only when the addon is opened by an user, instead of everytime the card is rendered.

```
function main(e){
   var mainCard = CardService.newCardBuilder();
   // Set up card sections
   UrlFetchApp.fetch(...) // Will perform the request even if addon is not opened
   return [card.build()]
}
```

Is it possible, to execute UrlFetchApp on card open instead of on render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/restrictions#use_apps_script_triggers), you cannot create or use Apps Script [simple](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) nor [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) in a Gmail add-on.

However, you can try looking into [time-driven triggers](https://goolgedev.blogspot.com/2018/05/create-time-driven-trigger-in-gmail-add.html) as a workaround.

> **Time-driven triggers**
>
> A time-driven trigger (also called a clock trigger) is similar to a
>   cron job in Unix. Time-driven triggers let scripts execute at a
>   particular time or on a recurring interval, as frequently as every
>   minute or as infrequently as once per month. (Note that an add-on can
>   use a time-driven trigger once per hour at most.)

You can also refer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50583457) for information on its usage.