# Trigger function upon archive/other action

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, google-apps

I'm trying to make a script that will automatically mark any message that has been archived as read upon archiving it. I have found that solutions for this do exist but they are all time based and I want mine to work instantly upon archiving (only checking when it needs to). Is it possible to have an action in Gmail (such as archiving a message) immediately trigger a function in `Google Apps Script`?

Help is greatly appreciated,
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have an action in Gmail (such as archiving a message) immediately trigger a function in `Google Apps Script`?

No.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/
- [Gmail Add-on trigger criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48843209/1595451)